# Computing the minimal eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, non-convex-optimization

One may compute the minimum eigenvalue of $ M \in \mathbb{S}_{++}^n$ by solving the problem
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize}_{ x} \quad x^TMx,\\
&\text{subject to} \quad \|x\|_2^2 \geq 1.
\end{align}

The optimal value of the problem is the minimum eigenvalue of $M$ that is obtained when $x$ is the eigenvector of $M$ associated with its minimum eigenvalue.

> Q: Determine whether the problem is convex. If not, please make convex relaxation to it so was to obtain a convex optimization.
>
> Hint: One may linearize the function in the constraint at each iteration.

I know this problem is not convex since the constraint is non-convex. But how to relax the constraint?

Comment: Did you mean $\|x\|_2^2 = 1$?

Comment: Are you familiar with penalty methods: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo No. In the question, it is $||x||_2^2 \geq 1$.

Comment: @AARON How does that make sense? It makes no sense to me. The eigenvalue problems I am familiar with measure gain, which involves ratio of norm of output to norm of input. If the norm of the input is $1$, then only the numerator is left. But that is not what you have, is it?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am not sure how to turn the "finding smallest eigenvalue" problem into such optimization problem. But I am sure that this is a correct claim. I have already know such problem is non-convex. Even though I relax the constraint to $||x||_2^2 = 1$, it is still non-convex and does not help.

Comment: Then $$x^\top M x \geq \lambda_{\min} (M) \|x\|_2^2 \geq \lambda_{\min} (M)$$ because $\lambda_{\min} (M) > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

By saying relaxing, I assume you accept an approximate solution. Actually, the hint of linearization also implies that. 
Firstly, by extending from @Casey's suggetion, this constraint problem can be reformulated as follows.
$$
minimize_x\hspace{1em}x^TMx\ +\ \phi_m(f_1(x))
$$
, where ϕ is the logarithmic penalty function.
$$
\phi_m(f_i(x))=-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{\ \ p‎}log(-f_i(x))
$$
f_i are the constraint functions in the original problem that satisfying
$$
f_i(x)\leq 0
$$
 So, here in this case, 
$$
f_1(x)= 1-x^Tx
$$
But we can linearize it as,
$$
f_1(x)\approx f_1(x_0)+\triangledown f_1(x_0)(x-x_0)=1-x_0^Tx_0-2x_0^T(x-x_0)
$$
Therefore, the original problem becomes an unconstraint problem for each m>0,
$$
minimize_x\hspace{1em}mx^TMx\ -\ log(2x_0^T(x-x_0)+x_0^Tx_0-1)
$$
Here we have an unconstrained convex problem, for which the cvx package in matlab, or any proper solvers, can solve. So you can iteratively find the optimal point x*(m) if x*(m) is close to the optimum at the previous iteration, say, x*(10m) is close to x*(m) if the iterative step for m is 10. 
By iteratively solving the problem for (m->+inf), the optimal point x*(m) will converge to the x* of the original problem.