# Convex relaxation

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am solving the following problem:

\begin{array}{ll}\min\limits_{{x:\,||x||_2^2\geq 1\\}} x^TAx,\end{array}
where $A$ is positive definite.

Since the constraint is not convex ($1-||x||_2^2\leq0$), this problem is not convex. I want to linearize the constraint function.

My attempt: for specific point $x_0$ and $f(x)=1-||x||_2^2$

$L(x_0)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)=1-||x_0||_2^2-2x_0^T(x-x_0)=1-||x_0||_2^2-2x_0^Tx+2||x_0||_2^2=1+||x_0||_2^2-2x_0^Tx$

New convex problem:

\begin{array}{ll}\min\limits_{{x:\,1+||x_0||_2^2-2x_0^Tx\leq0\\}} x^TAx,\end{array}

Is it the correct way?

Comment: Hint: $A - \lambda I$ is positive semidefinite if and only if all eigenvalues of $A$ are ...

Comment: Note that you can replace $\ge 1$ by $=1$ in the minimization problem. And then the solution is just the lowest eigenvalue.

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes, I understand that we are searching for minimum eigenvalue of $A$. But I want to use this specific linearization method for programming purpose.

Comment: What is $x_0$?.

Comment: @amsmath I want to solve this problem using cvx, and for each iteration linearize constraint to make the problem convex. So in the beginning I will set $x_0$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3405265/339790

Comment: Looks like you and Aaron are taking the same course!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes, you're right.